# setTimeout executes immediately instead of time passed in the function call

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I have this code to test the setTimeout function. The console.log is logged immediately after executing the code. Any idea why this function isn't called after 5 second? What is wrong with this code?

```js
function formatName(fname,lname){
  let fullName = fname+lname;
  console.log(fullName);
 }
setTimeout(formatName('Jon','Harris'),5000);

EDIT:
I didn't know about the way I need to call setTimeout.
```

Comment: None of the results when searching for _"settimeout immediately"_ fixed your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parameter of [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is the function, but in your code, you are executing the function. Make it as a function using arrow function.

```js
function formatName(fname,lname){
  let fullName = fname+lname;
  console.log(fullName);
 }
setTimeout(() => formatName('Jon','Harris'),5000);
```

Comment: Like in any of those possible [dupe targets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+settimeout+immediately)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters in the format:

```
setTimeout(formatName, 5000, fname, lname);
```

```js
function formatName(fname, lname){
  let fullName = fname + ' ' + lname;
  console.log(fullName);
}
 
setTimeout(formatName, 5000, 'Jon', 'Harris');
```